# What does arg1 command do?

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash, I have a simple question about the following code:

```
echo "xyz" > file
f1="xy"

while cat file | grep $f1 #this is inefficient, I know
do
  set arg1 $1 # ok what's that?!
done
```

cmd arguments: test1

Question 1: `set arg1 $1` sets the cmd arguments to "arg1 test1", correct? `arg1` is just a random name?

Question 2: while `cat file | grep $f1` returns true only if `$f1` exists in the file, otherwise it will not get inside the while loop. Correct?

Comment: Question 2: yes. In case it does match, it would loop forever, which is probably not what you want

Comment: Question 1: yes, correct. But please note that you most likely want to use ``set arg1 "$1"`` because ``$1`` can contain spaces.

Comment: yes, thanks. I understand the downvotes although this is not my code, but from a test I have on bash. Could you move your comments as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have answered your own questions.
[But do not forget about quotes around your variables.](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting)
Also you don't have to use `cat` for passing files to `grep` because `grep` allows you to specify the file.

Here is a bit improved version:

```
echo 'xyz' > file
f1='xy'

while grep -q "$f1" file; do # will loop forever if this file contains $f1 pattern.
    set arg1 "$1"
done
```

Comment: Unless the purpose of the `set` is specifically to split the value of `$1` on whitespace (or more generally the characters in `$IFS`), which is one common use case for `set`.

Comment: Also, you probably want `grep -q` to avoid having the matches printed continually to the screen.